# Recursively parse all the .md files from github repository and display the result in html format

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I'm new to Python and Flask.

Implementing using Flask framework.
Folder: F1->app.py,F2->a.md,b.md
When i run app.py , it displays link.html result(web page displays 2 links). When I click on the 1st link(F2/a.md), it should parse a.md file and render the result in html format. When I click on the second link(F2/b.md), it should parse b.md file and render the result in html format.

app.py :

```py
from flask import Flask,render_template

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('link.html')

@app.route('/Link')
def display():
#code to recursively read and parse the file->struck here
    return render.template("page.html")

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

link.html

```
<html>
<body>
<ul >
<li><a href="http://localhost:5000/link">F2/a.md</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost:5000/link">F2/b.md</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

page.html

```
<html>
<body>
{{ text|markdown }}
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Do you need to parse only the .MD file that was clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an arugment for rendering the markdown on the client side with Javascript, but for a basic example, this could be done on the server side with help of the Python library [mistune](https://pypi.org/project/mistune/):

```
pip install mistune
```

Let's have our app list the contents of the directory on startup.  Here we'll assume the markdown files are in the subdirectory `files/`:

```
from flask import Flask, abort, render_template
import os
import mistune

MD_DIR = 'files' # Dir containing .md files
md_files = [] # empty list to add .md files to

for file in os.listdir(MD_DIR):
    if file.endswith('.md'):
        md_files.append(file)

app = Flask(__name__)
```

`md_files` is now a list which contains all the files with a `.md` extension in the `files/` directory.

Now add a route which will do the listing.  We pass `md_files` to the template:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('link.html', md_files = md_files)
```

And a corresponding template to handle this at `templates/link.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>File List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
    {% for file in md_files %}
        <li>
            <a href='{{ url_for("render", file=file) }}'>{{ file }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice this uses the `url_for` function to build the list dynamically, based on what's in the `md_files` list.  Next we need to create our `render` function which takes an argument `file`:

```
@app.route('/render/<file>')
def render(file):
    if file not in md_files:
        abort(404)
    else:
        path = os.path.join(MD_DIR, file)
        with open(path) as f:
            data = f.read()

        return render_template('render.html', data=mistune.markdown(data))
```

This first checks that whatever was provided as `file` in the URL string is in fact in that `md_files` list, otherwise throws a 404.

If valid it reads the data and renders another template, setting the `data` variable to the return value of `mistune.markdown()` which gives us the HTML based on that markdown.

The template for this at `templates/render.html` should look like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    {{ data | safe }}
</body>
</html>
```

Notice we're using the `safe` filter, as we don't want the HTML provided in this variable to be escaped.

This is because what mistune does is returns HTML based on provided markdown.  This is best demonstrated at the terminal:

```
>>> import mistune
>>> mistune.markdown('# I am a header')
'<h1>I am a header</h1>\n'
>>>
```

The directory structure at this stage looks like:

```
.
├── app.py
├── files
│   ├── 1.md
│   └── 2.md
└── templates
    ├── link.html
    └── render.html
```

Some possible disadvantages with this approach:

- You need to restart the app to have it re-read what's in the `files/` subdirectory.  If that directory is going to be updated while the server is running, you could move the directory listing code into the `index` function, so the directory contents are listed on each request.  If the contents of the directory don't change this is probably in-efficient.

---

**EDIT** as per comment:

If you wish to recursively look for `.md` files in the `MD_DIR` folder you could use glob:

```
import glob
```

Then replace the for loop which builds `md_files` with:

```
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join (MD_DIR, "**/*.md"), recursive = True):
    if file.endswith('.md'):
        md_files.append(file)
```

This means items in `md_files` don't begin with `./` (which is the case in your `os.walk` modification), instead they look more like:

```
['files/1.md', 'files/2.md', 'files/subdir/deeptest.md']
```

This should be rendered in the links correctly, and of course in the `render` function, always ensure to:

```
    if file not in md_files:
        abort(404)
```

This ensures nothing is served if it's not in that `md_files` list.

Comment: I have done few modification to my code. But when i click on the link, it doesn't display the html page(shows 404 not found error) .

Comment: in url , localhost:5000/render/Folder1%5Ca.md-> why it's taking %5C instead of /?

Answer (score 0):

I have done few modification to my code.

```
from flask import Flask, abort, render_template
import os
import mistune
app=Flask(__name__)
md_files = []
for subdir, dirs,files in os.walk('./'):
    for file in files:
        if(file.endswith('.md')):
           md_files.append(os.path.join(subdir,file))
@app.route('/')
def index():
#link.html page produces the links [./Folder1/a.md,./Folder1/b.md, ./Folder2/a.md] as per my requirement.
    return render_template('link.html', md_files = md_files)

@app.route('/render/<file>')
def render(file):
   if file not in md_files:
      abort(404)
   else:
  #When i click on the link, it doesn't display the html page
  #I'm getting error(requested URL was not found on the server)
  #I think it's because file holds value like ./Folder1/a.md
  #I don't understand how to read that!
      with open(file) as f:
         data = f.read()

   return render_template('render.html', data=mistune.markdown(data)) 
if __name__=="__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)

Please help  me to solve this!
```